CMake include_directories to sibling directory
I am trying to include LibEigen to my Project. In my main Project I do have a lib Folder with another library of mine.
I do want to use LibEigen within my main project and within my own library.
Including libeigen in my mainproject works by simply adding
include_directories(lib/eigen/Eigen)

to my main CMakeLists.txt
However I cannot make libeigen work in its sibling library. Adding this to MyLibs CMakeLists.txt didn't resolve the issue.
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../eigen/Eigen)


Do not do it? Please provide more context how your CMakeLists.txt looks like. Best way is to import Eigen using find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE), see: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCMakeGuide.html (this should work out of the box if you have installed library on your system, or you may wish to use some package manager).

Including the last Eigen but in the header search path makes the internal includes (of the for Eigen/foo.h not work.

I agree with @MarekR make sure you use a package manager + find_package
